# Magento curl error 503 after ~60 seconds

Tags: php, magento, curl

I have developed a custom module for magento 1.9 that generates an XML feed with products to be used in an ERP.
I am using curl to run it with cron ( **curl http://url/action** ), but after about 60 seconds, I get a 503 error from magento.
I have increased **max_execution_time** to **300** (verified using phpinfo() ) but it seems to make no difference.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this? I am using a VPS server with Plesk.

Note: There are around 2000 products right now, so processing does need more than 60 seconds.

Comment: Did you get error like "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" ? or another error

Comment: That's what I get... but I noticed that the execution of the script seems to continue (the file is still being written until done)...

Answer (score 0):

Setting a global value of 300 for `max_execution_time` is a bit dangerous as this would allow normal (non-cURL) requests to execute for that amount time. (if it did end up working.) The reason that it may not be working is if `max_execution_time` is explicitly defined within your Magento installation root's `.htaccess` file.

Ideally, you would include `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` at the top of your Magneto module's controller so it will *only* run there for 5 minutes.

Comment: I am going to use ini_set when I can figure out what is going on. max_execution_time was not set in my .htacess file, but I tried setting it there as well, same results...